# injecting ServiceLocator via ServiceLocatorAwareInterface doesnt work

Tags: zend-framework2, service-locator

i read that implementing: ServiceLocatorAwareInterface will inject the serviceLocator to the same class. 
So I got this:

```
Class MyModel implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {


    protected $serviceLocator;


    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }


    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }
```

}

But  $this->serviceLocator is always NULL

Do i have to do more than that?

Answer (score 2):

You have to register your model in Service Config and retrieve it using service manager.
Here is an example:

```
/* Module.php */
public function getServiceConfig() {
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'my_model' => 'Application\Model\MyModel'
        )
    );
}

/* IndexController.php */
public function indexAction() {
    $model = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('my_model');
    $sl = $model->getServiceLocator(); // returns ServiceLocator
}
```

Comment: That means, i have to initiate every Model via Factory and i have to write down all my Models in the Module.php?

Or is there a solution to create an abstract Model with the SL injected and extend all other Models from it?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to inject Service Locator without Service Registration.

Comment: You can, rather than defining a factory for each model, add the model to the list of invokables. If you then create an AbstractModel class to extend from which implements the ServiceLocatorAwareInterface the service locator will be injected into every model as they are requested.