# ZF2 view helper in model

Tags: php, model, localization, zend-framework2, view-helpers

I'm localizing project written on ZF2. And in some places guys use static variables in Model layer.

```
    public function getTransitions()
    {
        $transitions = array(
            static::STATE_NEEDS_REVIEW         => 'Needs Review',
            static::STATE_NEEDS_REVISION       => 'Needs Revision',
            static::STATE_ARCHIVED             => 'Archive'
        );
//      some code...
        return $transitions;
    }
```

I have custom view helper for translation which is basically wrapper of ZF2 translator with some additional functionality. I know how to use it in view layer and in Controllers like this:

```
$t = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('t');
```

But how can use my view helper in Model layer ???

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the service locator in the model, you can implement ServiceLocatorAwareInterface, as described in the question and answer here:

[injecting ServiceLocator via ServiceLocatorAwareInterface doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075976/injecting-servicelocator-via-servicelocatorawareinterface-doesnt-work)

However, I would suggest that using a view helper in the model might not be the right way to go. Perhaps you could take the relevant logic from the ViewHelper and move it to a service that you can make available to the model class either via injection or just creating it when needed. The view helper could then use the same service.